# Add filter for specific post type only

Tags: filters

My filter works good, but for all pages and I need add filter only for specific post type.
I try it via is_singular, but not work.
My code:

```
    function my_super_filer_function6($query_args){
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
    global $post;
    $post_author = $post->post_author;
    $query_args['author'] = $post_author;   

    return $query_args->is_singular( $post_types );
}
}
add_filter('listing/grid/posts-query-args', 'my_super_filer_function6');
```

EDIT:
in other words how achieve this working code for specific post type:

```
function my_super_filer_function6($query_args){

    global $post;
    $post_author = $post->post_author;
    $query_args['author'] = $post_author;   

    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('listing/grid/posts-query-args', 'my_super_filer_function6');
```

Comment: listing/grid/posts-query-args Is not a core a WordPress hook, so it’s very difficult to say what the proper way to use it is without documentation.

Comment: This part is not important in this case, because this code works. I need this achieve for specific post type : `function my_super_filer_function6($query_args){
   
    global $post;
    $post_author = $post->post_author;
    $query_args['author'] = $post_author;   

    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('listing/grid/posts-query-args', 'my_super_filer_function6');`

Comment: Yes, it is important to know what the hook does. I can't tell from your code what `$query_args` is necessarily _supposed_ to be, or where the hook runs. `return $query_args->is_singular( $post_types );` is almost certainly nonsense, but I can't tell because there's no information on what `listing/grid/posts-query-args` is supposed to be or do. I can't even tell from your question what post type  you want to check. Is it the post type that this grid is embedded in? The post type that's listed _in_ the grid?

Comment: No this is only name of filter.

Comment: As I wrote I have this working function, but it works for whole website, and I need It only for CPT "events".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways you could handle this.

**Option 1** Check the `global $post` object

Inside your filter you may be able to check the current `$post` object or other [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for a specific type.

```
function my_super_filer_function6( $args ) {

    global $post;

    /* Check against the current post object */
    if( empty( $post ) || 'post_type_here' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return $args;
    }

    /* Check conditional tags */
    if( ! ( is_post_type_archive( 'post_type_here' ) || is_singular( 'post_type_here' ) ) ) {
        return $args;
    }

    /* ... */

}
```

**Option 2** Add the hook via [`template_redirect` or an early hook](https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/wordpress-core-load/)

You may be able to add the hook via an earlier action hook:

```
function wpse350295_init() {

    if( is_post_type_archive( 'post_type_here' ) || is_singular( 'post_type_here' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'listing/grid/posts-query-args', 'my_super_filer_function6' );
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse350295_init' );
```

**Option 3** Use the args

You may be able to check the passed args for a `post_type` and return early if the post type does not match what is expected:

```
function my_super_filer_function6($query_args){

    if( 'post_type' !== $query_args->get( 'post_type' ) ) {
        return $query_args
    }

    /* ... */

}
```

This is of course assuming what is being passed is a `WP_Query` object. You would need to do some due diligence to figure out what the passed variable holds and if a post type can be discerned from it.

Comment: Thank You, It works and help me lot.

Answer (score 1):

This will only execute that code for a specific post type:

```
function my_super_filer_function6($query_args){

    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'specific post type'){
        $post_author = $post->post_author;
        $query_args['author'] = $post_author;   
    }

    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('listing/grid/posts-query-args', 'my_super_filer_function6');
```

Comment: Thank You, It works and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working result from reply above:

```
function my_super_filer_function6( $query_args ) {
    global $post;    
    if($post->post_type == 'events'){
          $post_author = $post->post_author;
    $query_args['author'] = $post_author;   
    }    
    return $query_args;

}
add_filter('listing/grid/posts-query-args', 'my_super_filer_function6');
```